# "/pub/media/styles.css" not generated and some category images are not displayed

Tags: magento2, aws

Good Morning

I have been developing the following project that has the purpose of automating the construction of Magento2, in order to facilitate the evangelization of the platform

https://github.com/mozgbrasil/deploy-magento2#install

The installation of Magento works as expected by displaying all images from the "sample data"

But at the time of re-deploying the magento, it is that problems occur

https://github.com/mozgbrasil/deploy-magento2#deploy--re-deploy

Images of some categories are not displayed and the file "/pub/media/styles.css" that should be generated on the home page is not displayed

-

I even did the following test

delete the magento folder

I used the composer to download and install the magento

Access and test where it worked as expected

I renamed the magento folder

Then

I used the composer to download and redeploy the magento due to the presence of the database

This is where the problem happens

But if I rename this last deployment folder and use the previous one it works

-

To whom I can contribute with the project, I thank you

-

I have a deployment at AWS EBS in

http://304674501456-test-webapp014.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

The magento is in

http://304674501456-test-webapp014.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/magento/

and the backend in

http://304674501456-test-webapp014.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/magento/admin/

You can access how

admin / 123456a

-

See that you already have this link and the cache is disabled

-

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this link in Styles->Configurations->your_theme->HTML Head->Miscellaneous scripts

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}styles.css" />
```

Clean your cache and check it.

If not file appears try manually copying the styles.css into pub/media

Comment: I have reformulated my question and put the access data to the backend where we see that the link exists and the cache is disabled

As my project is public, I think it should be easier to implement a possible correction, if you can help now thank you